# Delete records that older some days, but if it delete all, keep last 20 records

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.0

i have something like this:

```
DELETE FROM `history` WHERE `date_field` <= now() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

but if all records is older than 10 days - this query deletes all! i want to keep last 20 records, even if they too old !

Please help, what and how i need to upd my code, and what will be better  use limit+offset of windowed function **OVER()**  or need smth another ?

Comment: I think it would be easier to create a new table with the last 20 rows, and then insert whatever else is left after the delete.

Comment: Tag your question with the version of MySQL.

Comment: You could do a subquery that selects the last 20 records and then do an outer left join on that.

Comment: You can't use window functions unless you're using MySQL 8.0. MySQL 5 doesn't have them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff v5.0added !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a subquery that gets the most recent 20 days and excludes them.

```
DELETE h1 
FROM history AS h1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM history
    ORDER BY date_field DESC
    LIMIT 20
) AS h2 ON h1.id = h2.id
WHERE date_field < now() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
AND h2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: exxelent!!! just checked, it dels all old if new > 20 and  if all records are old, keeps last 20 records ! Thnx alot!

Comment: exxelent!!! just finished my tests. if all records are old - it keeps only last 20 records and  works fine when mixed old+new also pritty when all new records ! Thnx alot!

Answer (score 0):

How about not using `delete` at all?  Write a query to save the records you want.  Then truncate the table and insert them back in:

```
create temporary table tokeep as
    select h.*
    from history h
    where `date_field` > now() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
    union
    select h.*
    from history h
    order by date_field desc
    limit 20;

truncate table history;

insert into history  -- the only situation where I don't list the columns
    select *
    from tokeep;
```